# Filter content by field with multiple values and different content type

Tags: views

I have 3 different content types:

- exhibitions
- events
- programs

All 3 content types have a *hashtags* field (a taxonomy term field).

I have a view with the following filter criteria.

- content type = "exhibitions, events, programs"

I created another content type (*general hashtags*) and it's only possible to create a single node of this content type.

This content type has a *filter hashtags* field (another taxonomy term field), where users enter all the hashtags they want.

I have a page called "hashtags" and I want to show all content filtered by the *filter hashtags* field, but I have four different content types.

I tried:

- filter criteria: "filter hashtags" is one of (options), is all of (options)
- relationship: hashtags and contextual filters: filter hashtags (tried with "taxonomy term ID from URL" and "content ID from URL")
- relationship: filter hashtags and contextual filters: hashtags (tried with "taxonomy term ID from URL" and "content ID from URL")

None of them works.

Is there a better way to achive this filter options?

I don't want to expose filters to visitors. I want a BO option only.

**Edited -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Maybe this can help to explain better my problem.

I want to achive the same result as exposed filter, like this eg.

[image: exposed filter]

**BUT** I don't want to expose this filter, instead I want this option as backoffice option where content editor can choose what hashtags will appear/filter.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? A View page that has some exposed filters on it? Or to match taxonomy from one CT to another CT? What is the purpose of one-page CT?

Comment: Hi, I want to create a hashtag page, for eg. when you click on a hashtag on IG or FB, you open a page with all content using a specific hashtag. My page will show all content using a specific hashtags (could be 1 hashtag or 10), but who choose this hashtags to show is my content creator. I want in my BO an option to choose some hashtags to show, like I said could be 1, 2 etc, I don't want to limit that choice, after that I want a page to show all content using those hashtags.

Comment: Do you know that there is "Taxonomy term" Views, already built in, you just have to enable it. It provides pages that list all content for a particular taxonomy term. Those can be modified to add more filters. What do you need on top of that?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Note that questions asking to suggest/find modules are off-topic for us. That is the reason why that question has been removed. It is also preferable to keep a single question per post. (In fact, there is a closing reason for questions asking multiple questions.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno thank you for your heads up.

Comment: @prkos I know it exist but it only display my taxonomy terms, do not display different content type based on taxonomy terms. Can you explain a little more? maybe I am not understanding your tip. Also I want to be abble list all content for a couple or more taxonomy term. Have a page showing all content type who have those hashtags. I already have a page showing all content type matching only ONE taxonomy term, my problem is to have the samething but with 2, 3, 4, etc taxonomy term